# How know which is the user who is login in java application?

Tags: java

I created a java application where login credentials are required to have access. How can I know which is the user who is logged in? Is there any way to know?

I do not know if they realized the doubt, if not I try to explain better.

----------------CODE-----------------

```
private void jBLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

String sql="select * from logins where username=? and password=? and idTipoLogin=?";
try{
    pst=(PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, jTUser.getText());
    pst.setString(2, jPass.getText());
    pst.setString(3, jComboBoxTipoLogin.getSelectedItem().toString());

    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){

        String idTipoLogin = rs.getString("idTipoLogin"); 

        if (idTipoLogin.equals("Administrador")) {

            jTTarefasAdmin ah = new jTTarefasAdmin();
            ah.setVisible(true);

        }
         else {
            jTTarefasTecnico eh = new jTTarefasTecnico();
            eh.setVisible(true);

        }
        this.setVisible(false);
        }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Invalid");
          }
        }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

}

[image]

The idea is to know what is the user who is logged into the system. 
As there are several users, I want to know specifically what is being accessed to login.

Comment: It's really useful to show what you've done already, and point to the problem with more details. If you're asking the question before any effort, please reconsider!

Comment: Thanks for reply. The idea is to know what is the user who is logged into the system. 
As there are several users, I want to know specifically what is being accessed to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a Collection of the logged in user, I think a HashMap would be good enough for your purpose.

```
 // This should be a class member
 Map<String, String> loggedInUsers = new HashMap<String, String>();

 // Now when user logs in add it to the HashMap
 loggedInUser.put(jTUser.getText(), jTUser.getText());

 // When a user logs out remove the user from the Map
 loggedInUser.remove(jTUser.getText());
```

If you just want a plain list of Users then you can store them in an ArrayList.

```
 List<String> loggedInUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
 loggedInUser.add(jTUser.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use the code that you post and this is the result: {rpr1=rpr1} What can I do for the result is rpr1 ?

Comment: This is the data in the Map...this means user rp1 is logged into the system. What you want to do with this depends on your application.

Comment: Because I needed to make a comparison with the result.

Comment: which result...what do you want to compare. I cannot see the code for the result. If you want to find the users that are in reuslt and also in loggedInUsers then you can iterate through the result and try to find the users in the Map

Comment: I did System.out.println (loggedInUsers) and the result was this {rpr1=rpr1} . I wanted this rpr1, and then list only information that user.

Comment: In that case store it in an ArrayList...I have edited my post

Comment: @ Kakarot how can I do to get the information that was recorded in the array, but in another form. That is, I recorded the information in arrayList in the Login form, now I want to get this information in another form. How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: @user3320956 can you specify what you mean by other form

Comment: Thanks for reply, but already solved my problem ;)
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you have one system that does the authentication of the user and the same user has access to other systems. On these other systems you want to know who the user is.

You could do this: Once the user is authenticated, create a unique id and put that in the session. Then access the session every time you need to know if the user is logged in. For other systems, pass that unique id to the system and allow them to query for the user.

Flow:
1. User logs in
2. System creates a unique id
3. Move that id with every request the user makes to other systems
4. On the other systems, allow them to access the authentication server and query based on the id.

This is a lot to do manually and there are plenty of systems out there that handle it all for you.

Links to get you started

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity